# Navigation Menu align one item to the right

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and i am trying to change a wordpress template in order to move the last item of my navigation menu to the right. I am using the following snippet:

```css
.menu-item-60146
{
      float:right;
}
/*
But i see no result

When i use the following code the navigation menu moves to the right but i need to move one item.

.boxwp-nav-secondary
{
      float:right;
}
What do i have to do to move an item to the right?
*/
```

```html
<nav>
<ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">

<li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Its working using #menu-item-60146 for some reason .menu-item-60146 is not working! There is another issue. At pc works ok but on tablets or smartphones the item merges with the other items and is aligned to the left under a sandwitch icon. Is there any way to seperate it in tablets and smartphones from the sandwitch icon which is place at top left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just float:right the last id. Also, just a suggestion, look into flexbox it's worth learning and will save you hours of time.

```css
#menu-item-60146
{
      float:right;
}
/*
But i see no result

When i use the following code the navigation menu moves to the right but i need to move one item.

.boxwp-nav-secondary
{
      float:right;
}
What do i have to do to move an item to the right?
*/
```

```html
<nav>
<ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">

<li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: whats the difference between #menu-item-60146{  float:right; } and .menu-item-60146
{float:right;} only when using the # symbol works!

Comment: generally when you have a class you have more than one element that's a member of that class.  Since you only wanted the last element selected I used # so as not to affect any other elements that might have that class name.  In the code I provided you can change the # to . and you will get the same result.  If it's not working in your code it's because you have other stuff going on, possibly other elements with the class name in question.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit to use standard styling for ul and li.  Feel free to replace ul and li with a class and style that class.

Here is a working version of your code.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.menu-item-60146 {
float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">

<li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Its working using #menu-item-60146 for some reason .menu-item-60146 is not working! There is another issue. At pc works ok but on tablets or smartphones the item merges with the other items and is aligned to the left under a sandwitch icon. Is there any way to seperate it in tablets and smartphones from the sandwitch icon which is place at top left? or maybe add two nav menu one on the left and one on the right at the top navigation menu?

Comment: I see you asked the same under the accepted answer but some people dont care after they get the reputation. So # is for id and dot is for class.  I removed all unwanted classes and used just `.menu-item-60146` and it works. I cant type an answer to your other question in this comment section. Can you ask a new question, add a picture or link for the other question?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I started a new question for the new issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64078402/align-item-of-primary-menu-to-the-right-works-but-does-not-display-correctly-on