# align item of primary menu to the right works but does not display correctly on tablet and smartphone

Tags: html, css

Hello I am new to CSS and I am using a snippet to align an item of my primary menu at my wordpress website to the right side.

```
#menu-item-60146 {
  float: right;
}
```

It works on PC and Mac as the picture shows. But it is not functioning the same way at tablets and smartphones. Check the pictures below:

[image: align item to the right PC and mac]

[image: not working properly on smartphones and tablets]

As you notice it keeps merging with the sandwich button on the top left side at smartphones and tablets. I need to make it work like on PC and mac. I need to keep five of the six items under the sandwich button and the sixth item to align  to the right top side of the primary menu in order to show up as in PC and mac. This is the desired result on mobile and tablets.

[image]

**The contact item has to stay on the top right regardless if the user taps or clicks on the hamburger. Even if the hamburger is not open the contact item has to stay on top right of the primary navigation menu.**
Do I have to add two separate menus on the primary menu to achieve the same result as in PC? If this is the right way how is this possible any example?

This is the output html code of the primary menu

```
<nav>
  <ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">

    <li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.menu-item-60146 {
float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
/* Top Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.boxwp-secondary-menu-container-inside{position:relative;}
.boxwp-nav-secondary:before{content:" ";display:table}
.boxwp-nav-secondary:after{clear:both;content:" ";display:table}
.boxwp-nav-secondary{float:none;background:#555555;border:0px solid #555555;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu{line-height:1;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;list-style:none;list-style-type:none;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu li{border-width:0;display:inline-block;margin:0;padding-bottom:0;text-align:left;float:left;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu a{border:none;color:#ffffff;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000000;display:block;padding:8px 15px;position:relative}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .current_page_item > a{text-decoration:none}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children{margin:0;padding:0;left:-9999px;opacity:0;position:absolute;-webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;width:190px;z-index:99;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children a{border:1px solid #666666;border-top:none;letter-spacing:0;padding:12px 15px;position:relative;width:190px}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu li:first-child a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children li:first-child a{border-top:1px solid #666666;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children .children{margin:-39px 0 0 189px}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover{position:static}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover > .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover > .children{left:auto;opacity:1}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu a{font:normal normal 13px Oswald,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu > li > a{text-transform:uppercase;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .current_page_item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children .current_page_item > a:hover{background:#000000;color:#dddddd;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children{background:#444444;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children a{padding:12px 15px}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children .current_page_item > a{color:#dddddd;}
.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon{cursor:pointer;display:none;margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:4px;margin-left:10px;text-align:left;}
.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon::before{color:#ffffff;content:"\f0c9";font:normal 18px/1 FontAwesome;margin:0 auto;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu > li > a{border-right:1px solid #666666;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu > li:first-child > a {border-left: 0px solid #666666;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1112px) {
#boxwp-secondary-navigation{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu li{float:none}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu{text-align:center}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu{display:none}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu li,.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon{display:block}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu li:hover{position:static}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu li.current-menu-item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu li.current-menu-item > a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu li.current_page_item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children li.current_page_item > a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu li a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu li a:hover{display:block;padding:15px 20px;border:none}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu li:first-child a{border-top:none;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu .children li:first-child a{border-top:none;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .menu-item-has-children,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .page_item_has_children{cursor:pointer}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .menu-item-has-children > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .page_item_has_children > a{margin-right:50px}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > .menu-item-has-children:before,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > .page_item_has_children:before{content:"\f107";float:right;font:normal 20px/1 FontAwesome;width:50px;height:20px;padding:10px 20px;right:0;text-align:right;z-index:9999;color:#ffffff;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000000;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .boxwp-secondary-menu-open.menu-item-has-children:before,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .boxwp-secondary-menu-open.page_item_has_children:before{content:"\f106";color:#ffffff;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000000;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > li > .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > li > .children{display:none}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children{left:auto;opacity:1;position:relative;-webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;width:100%;z-index:99;margin:0;}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children .children{background-color:transparent;margin:0;padding-left:15px}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu li a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu li a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children li a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children li a:hover{padding:12px 20px;position:relative;width:100%}
.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .current-menu-item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu li a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu li a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .sub-menu,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > .menu-item-has-children:before,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > .page_item_has_children:before,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .current_page_item > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children li a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children li a:hover,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu .children,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > .menu-item-has-children:before,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > .page_item_has_children:before,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu > li:hover > a,.boxwp-secondary-nav-menu.boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu a:hover{}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="boxwp-container boxwp-secondary-menu-container clearfix"><div class="boxwp-secondary-menu-container-inside clearfix"><nav class="boxwp-nav-secondary" id="boxwp-secondary-navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation"><div class="boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon"></div><ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu"><li id="menu-item-60187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60187"><a href="https://www.website.com/edit-profile/">Edit Profile</a></li><li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li><li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li><li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price Finder</a></li><li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/coupon-finder/">Coupon Finder</a></li><li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li></ul></nav></div></div>
```

Comment: On mobile, you want the contact and coupon finder added in columns to the right?

Comment: No, i want the contact item to show up seperately from the sandwich button on the right side of the primary menu like on PC and mac...

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? or codepen demo. so far tried.

Comment: I will try although i have no clue how to reproduce it, i just inspect the output and change the css

Comment: Is this a reproducible example? https://codepen.io/xagiate/pen/JjXzvwO

Comment: Your question is very unclear - you say "*I need to keep four of the six items under the sandwich button and the other two items to align them to the right side of the primary menu*", but then you say in the comments that you want *only the contact* to show uo separately. Can you show us an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/X7tSoYS this is what i want to achieve. If i will be able to move one of the six items like in the picture i will be able to move one more that is why i mention only one in the comments. Lets focus on the picture.

Comment: Calm down guys we are here to help each other not to argue. Lets focus on things that are connecting us.

Comment: I changed the question guys showing a picture of the desired result.

Comment: @stefanosn that makes the question much clearer for future users, thanks :) FYI, I've copied your codepen into the question as a Stack Snippet as this is the preferred way for runnable examples on SO. See [how to create a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Found the sandwich css code inside style.css if anyone can help please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using an absolute [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) along with a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-item-60146 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; /* play around to match your hamburger menu*/
    right: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">

    <li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

      <li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>

      <li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### EDIT 2

Here you go, replace your css and html with this

**html**

```
    <div class="boxwp-container boxwp-secondary-menu-container clearfix">
      <div class="boxwp-secondary-menu-container-inside clearfix">
        <nav class="boxwp-nav-secondary" id="boxwp-secondary-navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation">
          <div class="boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon"></div>

          <ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-60187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60187"><a href="https://www.website.com/edit-profile/">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price Finder</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/coupon-finder/">Coupon Finder</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul id="sticky-nav-menu" class="boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #sticky-nav-menu {
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    #boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    #boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation li a,
    #sticky-nav-menu li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font: normal normal 13px Oswald, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
    }

    #boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation li a:hover,
    #sticky-nav-menu li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }

    #sticky-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-60146 a {
      padding: 9px 20px;
    }

    #boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation li {
      float: left;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1112px) {
      #boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation li a,
      #sticky-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-60146 a {
        padding: 14px 16px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is going to work but i do not know where to add the ul class="custom-links". I mean i do not know where is the file that includes the code that generates the output.

Comment: "*Not exactly sure, but I think this is what you're looking for.*"... when a question is unclear (like this one!) you should hold off on answering until it has been improved to be clear and answerable. See [answer] and in particular the section "**Answer well-asked questions**". Otherwise all we can do is guess, which is not appropriate for a Q&A repository website like SO. Instead, you can ask for more information in the comments, flag the question as unclear, or simply move on to questions that are suitable to be part of the Stack Overflow site :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten it's already described by the OP in the comments with a screenshot.

Comment: Then why say you're not sure what they are looking for? That is a direct quote from your own answer :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Edited my sentence ;)

Comment: @Becky First of all Thanks for your answer. You css code is functioning when the hamburger is open but when it closes the contact item dissapears. I need to keep the contact item visible even when the hamburger is not open...

Comment: @Becky Any thoughts?

Comment: @stefanosn I can help you if I am able to see the hamburger menu. But I can not see it in your snippit. So try adding this to make it show on mobile `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { #boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation .menu-item.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-60146 { display: inline-block; } }`

Comment: @Becky I am searching for the hamburger menu source code but cant find it in the template i am using. Where this menu might be? Its a wordpress them called Boxwp https://wordpress.org/themes/boxwp/ but i do not know where to look!

Comment: @Becky tried the code just centers the contact item in the hamburger menu

Comment: @Becky I have updated my question you can check the result. Found the sandwich css code inside style.css if anyone can help please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @stefanosn I have updated my answer. Let me know if you need further help

Comment: Thank you but i dont know how to change the html output for this specific menu for the theme i am using but i will try. Any thoughts which file might include the code? Maybe i should use replace methods in functions.php of wordpress! I dont know.

Comment: @Becky Thanks i added it. I need to make a sub menu and make it show up on hover. I tried this <ul id="sticky-nav-menu" class="boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu"> <li id="menu-item-2711" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2711"><a href"#">Currency</a> <ul id="submenu" class="sub-menu"> <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27"><a href="website.com">EURO</a></li> </ul> </li> </ul>any help? its not working...

Comment: @Becky I managed to align the dropdown to the right side and managed to show the dropdown menu but the menu shows inside the navigation menu, i need to show up on hover outside of the navigation menu. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Becky i am accepting this answer as correct if you can help me showing the dropdown menu hover outside of the div navigation menu let me know please...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I converted your menu into two. Since you didnt supply the code for hamburger, I added my own. Depending on what language you are using, you may be able to make the menu a component or variable and reuse unlike how I had to repeat it twice.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var y = document.getElementById("ham");
  if (y.className == "container change") {
   y.classList.remove("change");
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
      document.getElementById("hide-mobile").style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
  y.classList.add("change");
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
   document.getElementById("hide-mobile").style.display = "none";
   
  }
  
}
```

```css
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}


/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 480px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .hide-mobile { display: none; }
  }


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.menu-item-60146 {
float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation {
 margin-left: 2rem;
}

#ham {
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
 margin-bottom: -2rem;
 color: '#fff';
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<nav>
<div class="container" id="ham" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
  <ul id="boxwp-menu-secondary-navigation" class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">
   <span id="hide-mobile">
    <li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147 hide-mobile"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175 hide-mobile"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946 hide-mobile"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793 hide-mobile"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>
    </span>

    <li id="menu-item-60146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60146"><a href="https://www.website.com/blog/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<nav>
  <ul class="boxwp-secondary-nav-menu boxwp-menu-secondary boxwp-secondary-responsive-menu">

<li id="menu-item-60147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-60147"><a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60175"><a href="https://www.website.com/favorites/">Favorites</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-60946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60946"><a href="https://www.website.com/price-finder/">Price</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-70793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70793"><a href="https://www.website.com/">Finder</a></li>


  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```